# How can I find out why a website looks different when I upload it to IIS?

Tags: html, css, iis, layout

Good day...

I've been working on a website project, that requires to be on a Microsoft IIS Web Server.
It is HTML, pure HTML, with really nice CSS, web-standards, etc.
I open this website using in my computer, using Firefox, IE 8.0, Safari, Google Chrome and it looks fine everywhere.

But as I upload it to the Microsoft IIS server, it changes a few things.
for example:

the main menu, which is a navigation bar that has dropdowns, seems to change it's line-height for some reason, and it is bigger. Some `<h3> or <h2>` Alignment seems wrong as well...

And the lines that are supposed to surround the photographs in the website (like a frame - dotted line) won't appear. But all the rest of the CSS is loading perfectly fine. I don't think it's a path problem as everything is loading fine. But this is making me look bad and it is very important to have this done as soon as possible.

**Can someone give me good suggestions on what to look at ?**

The IIS permissions seem fine. I'm not a big Microsoft fan...but I have to develop the website there.  Also, I uploaded the site to my apache server and it worked wonders. I wish I could change the policies in this corporation, but I can't. 
Thank you so much for your kind help.

Update:

To answer the request of some of the code, especially the heading until the body tag... here it is (without page title and content of the meta tags)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title></title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateParam name="categoria" type="text" value="home" -->
<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="title" content="" />
<meta name="creator" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="publisher" content="" />
<meta name="Description" content="" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="" />
<meta name="subject" content="" />

<!-- list of CSS to import -->
<link href="../css/main-client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />


<!-- Load Drop down menu CSS files  -->
<link href="../css/dropdown.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/default.advanced.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Load Drop down menus CSS files - END -->

<!--  Change of H2 or H3 font using CUFON -->
<script src="../cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../AFB_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('h2');
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            Cufon.replace('h3');
        </script> 
<!-- End of CUFON Load-->


<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>
```

**Update #2:**
I just noticed that this site is breaking in IE8.0 on IIS, but not in Firefox on IIS.
But it still looks good on my IE8.0 when i open the file from my computer.

**Update #3:**
I deactivated with  the Cufon lines, and the problem did persist. So I don't think it is a problem. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. But that's what I found out.

**Update #4:**
Playing with Compatibility Mode lead me to see my website running well on IE8.0
but the computer next door, still looks bad. And I shouldn't be using that option to make it look good, or else all the users would have to do the same, and that's not the idea.
I'm a little confused with QuirksMode, I just changed the doctype of the site, to HTML 4.01 Transitional, but things are pretty  much the same.
All the CSS files are loading...but is not being interpreted well.

and per your request...the  Cufon-yui code, it's horrible to look at this:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Simo Kinnunen.
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 *
 * @version 1.09
 */
var Cufon=(function(){var m=function(){return m.replace.apply(null,arguments)};var x=m.DOM={ready:(function(){var C=false,E={loaded:1,complete:1};var B=[],D=function(){if(C){return}C=true;for(var F;F=B.shift();F()){}};if(document.addEventListener){document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",D,false);window.addEventListener("pageshow",D,false)}if(!window.opera&&document.readyState){(function(){E[document.readyState]?D():setTimeout(arguments.callee,10)})()}if(document.readyState&&document.createStyleSheet){(function(){try{document.body.doScroll("left");D()}catch(F){setTimeout(arguments.callee,1)}})()}q(window,"load",D);return function(F){if(!arguments.length){D()}else{C?F():B.push(F)}}})(),root:function(){return document.documentElement||document.body}};var n=m.CSS={Size:function(C,B){this.value=parseFloat(C);this.unit=String(C).match(/[a-z%]*$/)[0]||"px";this.convert=function(D){return D/B*this.value};this.convertFrom=function(D){return D/this.value*B};this.toString=function(){return this.value+this.unit}},addClass:function(C,B){var D=C.className;C.className=D+(D&&" ")+B;return C},color:j(function(C){var B={};B.color=C.replace(/^rgba\((.*?),\s*([\d.]+)\)/,function(E,D,F){B.opacity=parseFloat(F);return"rgb("+D+")"});return B}),fontStretch:j(function(B){if(typeof B=="number"){return B}if(/%$/.test(B)){return parseFloat(B)/100}return{"ultra-condensed":0.5,"extra-condensed":0.625,condensed:0.75,"semi-condensed":0.875,"semi-expanded":1.125,expanded:1.25,"extra-expanded":1.5,"ultra-expanded":2}[B]||1}),getStyle:function(C){var B=document.defaultView;if(B&&B.getComputedStyle){return new a(B.getComputedStyle(C,null))}if(C.currentStyle){return new a(C.currentStyle)}return new a(C.style)},gradient:j(function(F){var G={id:F,type:F.match(/^-([a-z]+)-gradient\(/)[1],stops:[]},C=F.substr(F.indexOf("(")).match(/([\d.]+=)?(#[a-f0-9]+|[a-z]+\(.*?\)|[a-z]+)/ig);for(var E=0,B=C.length,D;E<B;++E){D=C[E].split("=",2).reverse();G.stops.push([D[1]||E/(B-1),D[0]])}return G}),quotedList:j(function(E){var D=[],C=/\s*((["'])([\s\S]*?[^\\])\2|[^,]+)\s*/g,B;while(B=C.exec(E)){D.push(B[3]||B[1])}return D}),recognizesMedia:j(function(G){var E=document.createElement("style"),D,C,B;E.type="text/css";E.media=G;try{E.appendChild(document.createTextNode("/**/"))}catch(F){}C=g("head")[0];C.insertBefore(E,C.firstChild);D=(E.sheet||E.styleSheet);B=D&&!D.disabled;C.removeChild(E);return B}),removeClass:function(D,C){var B=RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)"+C+"(?=\\s|$)","g");D.className=D.className.replace(B,"");return D},supports:function(D,C){var B=document.createElement("span").style;if(B[D]===undefined){return false}B[D]=C;return B[D]===C},textAlign:function(E,D,B,C){if(D.get("textAlign")=="right"){if(B>0){E=" "+E}}else{if(B<C-1){E+=" "}}return E},textShadow:j(function(F){if(F=="none"){return null}var E=[],G={},B,C=0;var D=/(#[a-f0-9]+|[a-z]+\(.*?\)|[a-z]+)|(-?[\d.]+[a-z%]*)|,/ig;while(B=D.exec(F)){if(B[0]==","){E.push(G);G={};C=0}else{if(B[1]){G.color=B[1]}else{G[["offX","offY","blur"][C++]]=B[2]}}}E.push(G);return E}),textTransform:(function(){var B={uppercase:function(C){return C.toUpperCase()},lowercase:function(C){return C.toLowerCase()},capitalize:function(C){return C.replace(/\b./g,function(D){return D.toUpperCase()})}};return function(E,D){var C=B[D.get("textTransform")];return C?C(E):E}})(),whiteSpace:(function(){var D={inline:1,"inline-block":1,"run-in":1};var C=/^\s+/,B=/\s+$/;return function(H,F,G,E){if(E){if(E.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="br"){H=H.replace(C,"")}}if(D[F.get("display")]){return H}if(!G.previousSibling){H=H.replace(C,"")}if(!G.nextSibling){H=H.replace(B,"")}return H}})()};n.ready=(function(){var B=!n.recognizesMedia("all"),E=false;var D=[],H=function(){B=true;for(var K;K=D.shift();K()){}};var I=g("link"),J=g("style");function C(K){return K.disabled||G(K.sheet,K.media||"screen")}function G(M,P){if(!n.recognizesMedia(P||"all")){return true}if(!M||M.disabled){return false}try{var Q=M.cssRules,O;if(Q){search:for(var L=0,K=Q.length;O=Q[L],L<K;++L){switch(O.type){case 2:break;case 3:if(!G(O.styleSheet,O.media.mediaText)){return false}break;default:break search}}}}catch(N){}return true}function F(){if(document.createStyleSheet){return true}var L,K;for(K=0;L=I[K];++K){if(L.rel.toLowerCase()=="stylesheet"&&!C(L)){return false}}for(K=0;L=J[K];++K){if(!C(L)){return false}}return true}x.ready(function(){if(!E){E=n.getStyle(document.body).isUsable()}if(B||(E&&F())){H()}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee,10)}});return function(K){if(B){K()}else{D.push(K)}}})();function s(D){var C=this.face=D.face,B={"\u0020":1,"\u00a0":1,"\u3000":1};this.glyphs=D.glyphs;this.w=D.w;this.baseSize=parseInt(C["units-per-em"],10);this.family=C["font-family"].toLowerCase();this.weight=C["font-weight"];this.style=C["font-style"]||"normal";this.viewBox=(function(){var F=C.bbox.split(/\s+/);var E={minX:parseInt(F[0],10),minY:parseInt(F[1],10),maxX:parseInt(F[2],10),maxY:parseInt(F[3],10)};E.width=E.maxX-E.minX;E.height=E.maxY-E.minY;E.toString=function(){return[this.minX,this.minY,this.width,this.height].join(" ")};return E})();this.ascent=-parseInt(C.ascent,10);this.descent=-parseInt(C.descent,10);this.height=-this.ascent+this.descent;this.spacing=function(L,N,E){var O=this.glyphs,M,K,G,P=[],F=0,J=-1,I=-1,H;while(H=L[++J]){M=O[H]||this.missingGlyph;if(!M){continue}if(K){F-=G=K[H]||0;P[I]-=G}F+=P[++I]=~~(M.w||this.w)+N+(B[H]?E:0);K=M.k}P.total=F;return P}}function f(){var C={},B={oblique:"italic",italic:"oblique"};this.add=function(D){(C[D.style]||(C[D.style]={}))[D.weight]=D};this.get=function(H,I){var G=C[H]||C[B[H]]||C.normal||C.italic||C.oblique;if(!G){return null}I={normal:400,bold:700}[I]||parseInt(I,10);if(G[I]){return G[I]}var E={1:1,99:0}[I%100],K=[],F,D;if(E===undefined){E=I>400}if(I==500){I=400}for(var J in G){if(!k(G,J)){continue}J=parseInt(J,10);if(!F||J<F){F=J}if(!D||J>D){D=J}K.push(J)}if(I<F){I=F}if(I>D){I=D}K.sort(function(M,L){return(E?(M>=I&&L>=I)?M<L:M>L:(M<=I&&L<=I)?M>L:M<L)?-1:1});return G[K[0]]}}function r(){function D(F,G){if(F.contains){return F.contains(G)}return F.compareDocumentPosition(G)&16}function B(G){var F=G.relatedTarget;if(!F||D(this,F)){return}C(this,G.type=="mouseover")}function E(F){C(this,F.type=="mouseenter")}function C(F,G){setTimeout(function(){var H=d.get(F).options;m.replace(F,G?h(H,H.hover):H,true)},10)}this.attach=function(F){if(F.onmouseenter===undefined){q(F,"mouseover",B);q(F,"mouseout",B)}else{q(F,"mouseenter",E);q(F,"mouseleave",E)}}}function u(){var C=[],D={};function B(H){var E=[],G;for(var F=0;G=H[F];++F){E[F]=C[D[G]]}return E}this.add=function(F,E){D[F]=C.push(E)-1};this.repeat=function(){var E=arguments.length?B(arguments):C,F;for(var G=0;F=E[G++];){m.replace(F[0],F[1],true)}}}function A(){var D={},B=0;function C(E){return E.cufid||(E.cufid=++B)}this.get=function(E){var F=C(E);return D[F]||(D[F]={})}}function a(B){var D={},C={};this.extend=function(E){for(var F in E){if(k(E,F)){D[F]=E[F]}}return this};this.get=function(E){return D[E]!=undefined?D[E]:B[E]};this.getSize=function(F,E){return C[F]||(C[F]=new n.Size(this.get(F),E))};this.isUsable=function(){return !!B}}function q(C,B,D){if(C.addEventListener){C.addEventListener(B,D,false)}else{if(C.attachEvent){C.attachEvent("on"+B,function(){return D.call(C,window.event)})}}}function v(C,B){var D=d.get(C);if(D.options){return C}if(B.hover&&B.hoverables[C.nodeName.toLowerCase()]){b.attach(C)}D.options=B;return C}function j(B){var C={};return function(D){if(!k(C,D)){C[D]=B.apply(null,arguments)}return C[D]}}function c(F,E){var B=n.quotedList(E.get("fontFamily").toLowerCase()),D;for(var C=0;D=B[C];++C){if(i[D]){return i[D].get(E.get("fontStyle"),E.get("fontWeight"))}}return null}function g(B){return document.getElementsByTagName(B)}function k(C,B){return C.hasOwnProperty(B)}function h(){var C={},B,F;for(var E=0,D=arguments.length;B=arguments[E],E<D;++E){for(F in B){if(k(B,F)){C[F]=B[F]}}}return C}function o(E,M,C,N,F,D){var K=document.createDocumentFragment(),H;if(M===""){return K}var L=N.separate;var I=M.split(p[L]),B=(L=="words");if(B&&t){if(/^\s/.test(M)){I.unshift("")}if(/\s$/.test(M)){I.push("")}}for(var J=0,G=I.length;J<G;++J){H=z[N.engine](E,B?n.textAlign(I[J],C,J,G):I[J],C,N,F,D,J<G-1);if(H){K.appendChild(H)}}return K}function l(D,M){var C=D.nodeName.toLowerCase();if(M.ignore[C]){return}var E=!M.textless[C];var B=n.getStyle(v(D,M)).extend(M);var F=c(D,B),G,K,I,H,L,J;if(!F){return}for(G=D.firstChild;G;G=I){K=G.nodeType;I=G.nextSibling;if(E&&K==3){if(H){H.appendData(G.data);D.removeChild(G)}else{H=G}if(I){continue}}if(H){D.replaceChild(o(F,n.whiteSpace(H.data,B,H,J),B,M,G,D),H);H=null}if(K==1){if(G.firstChild){if(G.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="cufon"){z[M.engine](F,null,B,M,G,D)}else{arguments.callee(G,M)}}J=G}}}var t=" ".split(/\s+/).length==0;var d=new A();var b=new r();var y=new u();var e=false;var z={},i={},w={autoDetect:false,engine:null,forceHitArea:false,hover:false,hoverables:{a:true},ignore:{applet:1,canvas:1,col:1,colgroup:1,head:1,iframe:1,map:1,optgroup:1,option:1,script:1,select:1,style:1,textarea:1,title:1,pre:1},printable:true,selector:(window.Sizzle||(window.jQuery&&function(B){return jQuery(B)})||(window.dojo&&dojo.query)||(window.Ext&&Ext.query)||(window.YAHOO&&YAHOO.util&&YAHOO.util.Selector&&YAHOO.util.Selector.query)||(window.$$&&function(B){return $$(B)})||(window.$&&function(B){return $(B)})||(document.querySelectorAll&&function(B){return document.querySelectorAll(B)})||g),separate:"words",textless:{dl:1,html:1,ol:1,table:1,tbody:1,thead:1,tfoot:1,tr:1,ul:1},textShadow:"none"};var p={words:/\s/.test("\u00a0")?/[^\S\u00a0]+/:/\s+/,characters:"",none:/^/};m.now=function(){x.ready();return m};m.refresh=function(){y.repeat.apply(y,arguments);return m};m.registerEngine=function(C,B){if(!B){return m}z[C]=B;return m.set("engine",C)};m.registerFont=function(D){if(!D){return m}var B=new s(D),C=B.family;if(!i[C]){i[C]=new f()}i[C].add(B);return m.set("fontFamily",'"'+C+'"')};m.replace=function(D,C,B){C=h(w,C);if(!C.engine){return m}if(!e){n.addClass(x.root(),"cufon-active cufon-loading");n.ready(function(){n.addClass(n.removeClass(x.root(),"cufon-loading"),"cufon-ready")});e=true}if(C.hover){C.forceHitArea=true}if(C.autoDetect){delete C.fontFamily}if(typeof C.textShadow=="string"){C.textShadow=n.textShadow(C.textShadow)}if(typeof C.color=="string"&&/^-/.test(C.color)){C.textGradient=n.gradient(C.color)}else{delete C.textGradient}if(!B){y.add(D,arguments)}if(D.nodeType||typeof D=="string"){D=[D]}n.ready(function(){for(var F=0,E=D.length;F<E;++F){var G=D[F];if(typeof G=="string"){m.replace(C.selector(G),C,true)}else{l(G,C)}}});return m};m.set=function(B,C){w[B]=C;return m};return m})();Cufon.registerEngine("canvas",(function(){var b=document.createElement("canvas");if(!b||!b.getContext||!b.getContext.apply){return}b=null;var a=Cufon.CSS.supports("display","inline-block");var e=!a&&(document.compatMode=="BackCompat"||/frameset|transitional/i.test(document.doctype.publicId));var f=document.createElement("style");f.type="text/css";f.appendChild(document.createTextNode(("cufon{text-indent:0;}@media screen,projection{cufon{display:inline;display:inline-block;position:relative;vertical-align:middle;"+(e?"":"font-size:1px;line-height:1px;")+"}cufon cufontext{display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-10000in;}"+(a?"cufon canvas{position:relative;}":"cufon canvas{position:absolute;}")+"}@media print{cufon{padding:0;}cufon canvas{display:none;}}").replace(/;/g,"!important;")));document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(f);function d(p,h){var n=0,m=0;var g=[],o=/([mrvxe])([^a-z]*)/g,k;generate:for(var j=0;k=o.exec(p);++j){var l=k[2].split(",");switch(k[1]){case"v":g[j]={m:"bezierCurveTo",a:[n+~~l[0],m+~~l[1],n+~~l[2],m+~~l[3],n+=~~l[4],m+=~~l[5]]};break;case"r":g[j]={m:"lineTo",a:[n+=~~l[0],m+=~~l[1]]};break;case"m":g[j]={m:"moveTo",a:[n=~~l[0],m=~~l[1]]};break;case"x":g[j]={m:"closePath"};break;case"e":break generate}h[g[j].m].apply(h,g[j].a)}return g}function c(m,k){for(var j=0,h=m.length;j<h;++j){var g=m[j];k[g.m].apply(k,g.a)}}return function(V,w,P,t,C,W){var k=(w===null);if(k){w=C.getAttribute("alt")}var A=V.viewBox;var m=P.getSize("fontSize",V.baseSize);var B=0,O=0,N=0,u=0;var z=t.textShadow,L=[];if(z){for(var U=z.length;U--;){var F=z[U];var K=m.convertFrom(parseFloat(F.offX));var I=m.convertFrom(parseFloat(F.offY));L[U]=[K,I];if(I<B){B=I}if(K>O){O=K}if(I>N){N=I}if(K<u){u=K}}}var Z=Cufon.CSS.textTransform(w,P).split("");var E=V.spacing(Z,~~m.convertFrom(parseFloat(P.get("letterSpacing"))||0),~~m.convertFrom(parseFloat(P.get("wordSpacing"))||0));if(!E.length){return null}var h=E.total;O+=A.width-E[E.length-1];u+=A.minX;var s,n;if(k){s=C;n=C.firstChild}else{s=document.createElement("cufon");s.className="cufon cufon-canvas";s.setAttribute("alt",w);n=document.createElement("canvas");s.appendChild(n);if(t.printable){var S=document.createElement("cufontext");S.appendChild(document.createTextNode(w));s.appendChild(S)}}var aa=s.style;var H=n.style;var j=m.convert(A.height);var Y=Math.ceil(j);var M=Y/j;var G=M*Cufon.CSS.fontStretch(P.get("fontStretch"));var J=h*G;var Q=Math.ceil(m.convert(J+O-u));var o=Math.ceil(m.convert(A.height-B+N));n.width=Q;n.height=o;H.width=Q+"px";H.height=o+"px";B+=A.minY;H.top=Math.round(m.convert(B-V.ascent))+"px";H.left=Math.round(m.convert(u))+"px";var r=Math.max(Math.ceil(m.convert(J)),0)+"px";if(a){aa.width=r;aa.height=m.convert(V.height)+"px"}else{aa.paddingLeft=r;aa.paddingBottom=(m.convert(V.height)-1)+"px"}var X=n.getContext("2d"),D=j/A.height;X.scale(D,D*M);X.translate(-u,-B);X.save();function T(){var x=V.glyphs,ab,l=-1,g=-1,y;X.scale(G,1);while(y=Z[++l]){var ab=x[Z[l]]||V.missingGlyph;if(!ab){continue}if(ab.d){X.beginPath();if(ab.code){c(ab.code,X)}else{ab.code=d("m"+ab.d,X)}X.fill()}X.translate(E[++g],0)}X.restore()}if(z){for(var U=z.length;U--;){var F=z[U];X.save();X.fillStyle=F.color;X.translate.apply(X,L[U]);T()}}var q=t.textGradient;if(q){var v=q.stops,p=X.createLinearGradient(0,A.minY,0,A.maxY);for(var U=0,R=v.length;U<R;++U){p.addColorStop.apply(p,v[U])}X.fillStyle=p}else{X.fillStyle=P.get("color")}T();return s}})());Cufon.registerEngine("vml",(function(){var e=document.namespaces;if(!e){return}e.add("cvml","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");e=null;var b=document.createElement("cvml:shape");b.style.behavior="url(#default#VML)";if(!b.coordsize){return}b=null;var h=(document.documentMode||0)<8;document.write(('<style type="text/css">cufoncanvas{text-indent:0;}@media screen{cvml\\:shape,cvml\\:rect,cvml\\:fill,cvml\\:shadow{behavior:url(#default#VML);display:block;antialias:true;position:absolute;}cufoncanvas{position:absolute;text-align:left;}cufon{display:inline-block;position:relative;vertical-align:'+(h?"middle":"text-bottom")+";}cufon cufontext{position:absolute;left:-10000in;font-size:1px;}a cufon{cursor:pointer}}@media print{cufon cufoncanvas{display:none;}}</style>").replace(/;/g,"!important;"));function c(i,j){return a(i,/(?:em|ex|%)$|^[a-z-]+$/i.test(j)?"1em":j)}function a(l,m){if(m==="0"){return 0}if(/px$/i.test(m)){return parseFloat(m)}var k=l.style.left,j=l.runtimeStyle.left;l.runtimeStyle.left=l.currentStyle.left;l.style.left=m.replace("%","em");var i=l.style.pixelLeft;l.style.left=k;l.runtimeStyle.left=j;return i}function f(l,k,j,n){var i="computed"+n,m=k[i];if(isNaN(m)){m=k.get(n);k[i]=m=(m=="normal")?0:~~j.convertFrom(a(l,m))}return m}var g={};function d(p){var q=p.id;if(!g[q]){var n=p.stops,o=document.createElement("cvml:fill"),i=[];o.type="gradient";o.angle=180;o.focus="0";o.method="sigma";o.color=n[0][1];for(var m=1,l=n.length-1;m<l;++m){i.push(n[m][0]*100+"% "+n[m][1])}o.colors=i.join(",");o.color2=n[l][1];g[q]=o}return g[q]}return function(ac,G,Y,C,K,ad,W){var n=(G===null);if(n){G=K.alt}var I=ac.viewBox;var p=Y.computedFontSize||(Y.computedFontSize=new Cufon.CSS.Size(c(ad,Y.get("fontSize"))+"px",ac.baseSize));var y,q;if(n){y=K;q=K.firstChild}else{y=document.createElement("cufon");y.className="cufon cufon-vml";y.alt=G;q=document.createElement("cufoncanvas");y.appendChild(q);if(C.printable){var Z=document.createElement("cufontext");Z.appendChild(document.createTextNode(G));y.appendChild(Z)}if(!W){y.appendChild(document.createElement("cvml:shape"))}}var ai=y.style;var R=q.style;var l=p.convert(I.height),af=Math.ceil(l);var V=af/l;var P=V*Cufon.CSS.fontStretch(Y.get("fontStretch"));var U=I.minX,T=I.minY;R.height=af;R.top=Math.round(p.convert(T-ac.ascent));R.left=Math.round(p.convert(U));ai.height=p.convert(ac.height)+"px";var F=Y.get("color");var ag=Cufon.CSS.textTransform(G,Y).split("");var L=ac.spacing(ag,f(ad,Y,p,"letterSpacing"),f(ad,Y,p,"wordSpacing"));if(!L.length){return null}var k=L.total;var x=-U+k+(I.width-L[L.length-1]);var ah=p.convert(x*P),X=Math.round(ah);var O=x+","+I.height,m;var J="r"+O+"ns";var u=C.textGradient&&d(C.textGradient);var o=ac.glyphs,S=0;var H=C.textShadow;var ab=-1,aa=0,w;while(w=ag[++ab]){var D=o[ag[ab]]||ac.missingGlyph,v;if(!D){continue}if(n){v=q.childNodes[aa];while(v.firstChild){v.removeChild(v.firstChild)}}else{v=document.createElement("cvml:shape");q.appendChild(v)}v.stroked="f";v.coordsize=O;v.coordorigin=m=(U-S)+","+T;v.path=(D.d?"m"+D.d+"xe":"")+"m"+m+J;v.fillcolor=F;if(u){v.appendChild(u.cloneNode(false))}var ae=v.style;ae.width=X;ae.height=af;if(H){var s=H[0],r=H[1];var B=Cufon.CSS.color(s.color),z;var N=document.createElement("cvml:shadow");N.on="t";N.color=B.color;N.offset=s.offX+","+s.offY;if(r){z=Cufon.CSS.color(r.color);N.type="double";N.color2=z.color;N.offset2=r.offX+","+r.offY}N.opacity=B.opacity||(z&&z.opacity)||1;v.appendChild(N)}S+=L[aa++]}var M=v.nextSibling,t,A;if(C.forceHitArea){if(!M){M=document.createElement("cvml:rect");M.stroked="f";M.className="cufon-vml-cover";t=document.createElement("cvml:fill");t.opacity=0;M.appendChild(t);q.appendChild(M)}A=M.style;A.width=X;A.height=af}else{if(M){q.removeChild(M)}}ai.width=Math.max(Math.ceil(p.convert(k*P)),0);if(h){var Q=Y.computedYAdjust;if(Q===undefined){var E=Y.get("lineHeight");if(E=="normal"){E="1em"}else{if(!isNaN(E)){E+="em"}}Y.computedYAdjust=Q=0.5*(a(ad,E)-parseFloat(ai.height))}if(Q){ai.marginTop=Math.ceil(Q)+"px";ai.marginBottom=Q+"px"}}return y}})());
```

**Update #5**
I removed the URLs of the website, so the company's privacy remains.
This is the index.html response header...using Firefox, but remember in Firefox it looks fine. I dont know how to find it via IE.

```
GET /test-1/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: *
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://test-1/contact-us.html
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 08 Apr 2010 16:32:15 GMT
If-None-Match: "cc980c39d7ca1:15ce"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Apr 2010 16:32:15 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Etag: "cc980c39d7ca1:15ce"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2010 18:59:45 GMT
```

Answer (score 3):

> Update #2: I just noticed that this site is breaking in IE8.0 on IIS, but not in Firefox on IIS. But it still looks good on my IE8.0 when i open the file from my computer.

Thus, it is running in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Check the page source (rightclick, *View Source*) and the response headers. Does the page source look fine? No whitespace before `<!doctype>`? It would trigger IE in quirks mode. No odd response headers which forces IE to render/emulate in quirks mode? Does it have correct `Content-Type` header? IE namely doesn't support `application/xhtml+xml`, the server has to send it as `text/html`.

> Update #4: Playing with Compatibility Mode lead me to see my website running well on IE8.0 but the computer next door, still looks bad.

This confirms that IE was running in quirks mode.

> And I shouldn't be using that option to make it look good, or else all the users would have to do the same, and that's not the idea. I'm a little confused with QuirksMode, I just changed the doctype of the site, to HTML 4.01 Transitional, but things are pretty much the same. All the CSS files are loading...but is not being interpreted well.

You shouldn't change the doctype. You're using XHTML strict which is okay (it will render IE in [(almost) standards mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)), even though I would prefer HTML strict since this doesn't seem to be autogenerated code which uses a XML tool to parse components.

Once again, did you check the page source? There should be **no whitespace** before the `<!doctype>` line. No linefeed/newline, no spaces/tabs, no BOM characters, etcetera. The `<` must be the firstmost character. Use a hex editor if necessary. Did you check the **real** response headers? I don't mean the HTML `<meta>` tags, they are part of the response body. You can use under each Fiddler or a webbrowser-specific "http header" plugin for this, Google can find them.

Comment: This is the content type:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Oh, and this is the NEW Doctype
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: This would force IE in quirksmode. You **do not** want to have that. Now you're *guaranteeing* that it would look differently in all browsers, regardless of where it's hosted. Keep it `strict` and look for the cause somewhere else. Read this as well: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ Also, changing between HTML and XHTML is not just switching of doctype. You would also need to fix the XHTML style tags into HTML style tags. The w3 validator can help a lot in this. Don't do this yet. Keep the doctype XHTML strict and naildown the root cause first.

Comment: I'm working in Strict mode back again.  There's no white space before the doctype line, no new line, no spaces or tabs, no bom characters in the source code.

Comment: Left behind the response headers. Tell more.

Comment: I downloaded a Firefox plugin called Live HTTP Headers...but my site looks alright in Firefox. And the information am seeing there is 
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 103
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date

Comment: The response headers of the webpage in question, not the request and response headers of the favicon.ico, please :)

Comment: Updated the question and included your request. Sorry about that, copied the wrong one :-S

Comment: That's a partial (cached) response. Please clear browser cache or hit `Ctrl+F5` so that you get a HTTP 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

can you paste some code to look at? Perhaps the beginning html tag through opening body tag at least.  also, what version IIS?

EDIT:

```
<script src="../cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../AFB_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Those are suspect.  One or both have cross-browser issues is my guess. Any chance you can post source to those?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added the code on my question , please read the question again as it contains the requested code.
Thanks !

Comment: Like other answer below, problem appears to be Cufon.js related.  Something the jscript is doing isn't cross-browser friendly.

Comment: Well, I deactivated Cufon at all, and the problem persists. I'm going to write an update on my question.

Answer (score 0):

try using the firebug extension on firefox, and investigating what css styles get loaded, what the browsers requesting, ect. In theory it should all be working so i'm not sure what to suggest, but first point of call when debugging is to check your code is being loaded in properly and not being overridden by other code

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm gonna try and see if something is not overridden by other code. I hope not ! But I dont think so...I wrote this carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If it is, as you say, pure html & css, IIS shouldn't touch it at all. Without some actual code to look at, I don't know what else to suggest.

EDIT

Having seen your edit to include the source code, it's pretty clear from the symptoms you describe that this is a problem with cufon, not IIS.

Comment: That's precisely what I think. But why would it look fine everywhere except for IIS ? Even if i look at it using Explorer on my hard drive, it looks fine !

Comment: I just downloaded the Firebug plugin, and checked the IIS site with firefox and it looks fine, it is breaking in IE8.0 on IIS...not breaking on IE8.0 in my computer alone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just tried deactivating the Cufon script, and loaded the page again back on IIS, and the problem persists, but with ugly fonts he he

Comment: well, if it breaks on IE but not on HTML browsers, it seems clear that it's a microsoft thing.  it must be applying different behaviors after some chatting with the IIS.  especially if you're using a third party JS, and not "HTML, pure HTML" as you originally said.  remember that IE doesn't have JavaScript, it's a MS-only 'JScript' thing.

Comment: It seems I wasn't explaining myself very well... When I said 'pure html' I wanted to mean it was not a "aspx" (.net) site. Accept my apologies for misleading you with my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a recursive downloader (like `wget`) to pull the whole site from IIS.  then use `diff` to compare it with your original tree.  If there's any difference, blame IIS; if not, maybe the browsers apply initial CSS differently (you're using a reset CSS, right?)

Comment: I'm going to try WGet as you suggest... and Diff as well. I've never seen these tools before.  Thank you for enlightening me with new ideas.  I'm using a CSS Reset file, indeed.